# How to combine find_all() and find_next() in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have such pieces of HTML that I'm trying to parse. What I want to grab is the price ("84.00 USD"):

```
<div class="HeaderAndValues_headerDetailSection__3c2SZ ProductCatalog_price__25i2r">
      <div class="HeaderAndValues_header__3dB61">Wholesale</div>
      <span class="notranslate">
        <div class="">84.00 USD</div>
      </span>
    </div>
```

`soup.find(text="Wholesale").find_next().text` gives me exactly what I need but only for the first search result. Is there anyway I could combine find_all() and find_next()? smth like `soup.find_all(text="Wholesale").find_next()` that would grab next text for each found "Wholesale"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found it! Someone might still find it useful

```
[x.find_next().text for x in page.find_all(text = "Wholesale")]
```